# Solidiy remix VM error: revert

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript-vm

I am kinda new to solidity and I have this error that keeps popping up after I deployed the contract and run the initTest() function. What I am trying to do is passing the string that I insert in the initTest() on the runTest so it runs and save the entire string on the blockchain. I don't have any error when I compile the contrct, only after I deployed it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "../contracts/Code.sol";

contract CodeTest {

    ContrIdCard private _UniCode;
    bytes[] private CustID;      
    bytes[] private ContractID ;
  
   function pubblishCode (bytes memory _CustID, bytes memory _ContractID, bool _MultiCustID) private {
       _UniCode.mkCode(_CustID, _ContractID, _MultiCustID);
   }

   function initTest() public {
      uint i = 0;
      CustID[i] = "04wT9Os3uv7p"; ContractID[i++] = "e7tk6peihfcc6ece1ffbe8f8cd433ae61c1081ae6b94";
   }
   
   function runTest(bool _MultiCustID) public {
        for (uint i = 0; i<CustID.length; i++)
            pubblishCode (CustID[i], ContractID[i], _MultiCustID); 
   }
   
   function runTest() public {
        runTest(false);
   } 
}
```

The error given when I run initTest() is: "transact to CodeTest.initTest errored: VM error: revert.

revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information."

When I do the debug it gives me value 0 for the CustID e ContractID. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the function *initTest*:

1. Your index variable **i** is declared inside the function so the counter is not persistent so you won't have your planned logic as it always equals to 0 when a function is called.
2. You cannot assign new values to elements of an array that do not exist yet. Use `.push(value)` to append to an array.